# How to Create relationship between Two Properties for single node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a table looks like below:

| Drug | Reaction |
| --- | --- |
| ECS | INFLUENZA |
| ECS | HEAD PAIN |
| MAZA | HEAD PAIN |

i imported from psql to Neo4j.I have this single table for this How can i make realtionships between drug and reaction in Neo4j.

Comment: if they are in a single node, they are already related. How did you imported the data?

Comment: I have wroted using C# imported the data and
this is the Query : 
string query = "MERGE (d:Signal {id:'" + x + "', drug:'" + y + "' , reaction:'" + z + "'})";

Comment: now i have created the reationship refered this following link 
https://community.neo4j.com/t5/general-discussions/how-to-create-a-relationship-to-a-single-node/m-p/60364
and my query here:
string query = "MERGE (d:Signal {id:'" + x + "', drug:'" + y + "'})" +"MERGE (r:Signal {id:'" + x + "' , reaction:'" + z + "'})" + "MERGE (d)-[s:SIdeEffects]->(r)";

Comment: The above query is it right?

Comment: The second query seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Consider modeling (1) a set of nodes [with the Label: Drug] to represent Drugs, and (2) a set of nodes [with the label: Reaction] to represent the Reactions.

Then, you can define a suitable set of relationships between the two concepts.

Check out the Graph Data Modeling course on GraphAcademy or the [Developer Guidelines on Graph Data Modeling](https://neo4j.com/developer/data-modeling/) for a good baseline understanding of the topic.